# Passing this.state into static function

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set the `headerTitle` in the header bar to be the username of the logged in user: `this.state.username`. However, when I try to set `navigationOptions` to a function, I am unable to pass in the current state.

What would be the best way to set the headerTitle inside the `static navigationOptions`? I believe that `navigationOptions` must remain static, otherwise nothing will be displayed.

```react-native
class profile extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = 
    {
        headerTitle: this.state.username
    };
```

```react-native
const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: home,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="home" size={25} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
      },


    },
    Explore: {
      screen: explore,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="search" size={25} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="person" size={25} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
      }
    },
    Create: {
      screen: createCompetition,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="add" size={25} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
      }
    },
    Payment: {
      screen: payment,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="attach-money" size={25} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
        ),
        title: 'Payment',

      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: 'black',
      style: { backgroundColor: 'white', }
    },

  },
)
```

```react-native
TabStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
  const childOptions = getActiveChildNavigationOptions(navigation, screenProps)
  return {
    title: childOptions.title,
    headerLeft: childOptions.headerLeft,
    headerRight: childOptions.headerRight,
  }
}
```

Comment: can i suggest something? like these are the nitty gritties i always faced. so ive decided , ive disabled the navigation header and make my own custom global header which i will import. Hope you get that. if you want i can show a demo so that you can achieve too,

Comment: Yes, that will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of using react navigation Header ive disabled it and used my own cutsom,

This is my Header.js :

```
import React, {Fragment, Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import {headerStyles} from '../style/headerStyles';

export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          paddingBottom: hp('3.125%'),
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View style={{opacity: 0}}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/images/crossIcon.png')} />
        </View>
        <View style={{flexShrink: 1}}>
          <Text style={headerStyles.headerText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{left: -20, paddingLeft: 10, marginLeft: 10}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={headerStyles.imageView}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
            <Image
              style={{height: 15, width: 15}}
              source={require('../assets/images/crossIcon.png')}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and you can import in any component like :

```
import Header from '../components/Header';

return(
 <Header title={this.state.userName} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
)
```

With this you have enough power to do anything you want with header.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using react-navigation, I suggest you set a navigation param in your component and then get the param in the navigationOptions.

after login do this:

```
navigation.setParams({ headerTitle: this.state.userName})
```

and then inside your navigationOptions where you already have navigation:

```
return { title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle') }
```